# Luis Api 'FewLabels' issue

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am developing bot using LUIS framework by Microsoft. I am able to create application, Intent and utterances but when I try to train and publish my bot I am getting following error.

```
{
  modelId: 'some-model-id',
  details: {
    statusId: 1,
    status: 'Fail',
    exampleCount: 0,
    failureReason: 'FewLabels'
  }
}
```

Because of this I am not able to publish my LUIS application. I don't find much information about the cause and prevention of this issue in Microsoft documents.

Comment: You got this `FewLabels` during training, right? it's because one of your intents has no utterances, so training cannot compete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Nicolas R.

This is because of zero utterances in one of the intent while training.
So if you are using Luis Api make sure that each intent atleast have one utterance.

`FewLabels` seems to be a wrong failure Reason though, it should be like `NoUtterance` or `ZeroUtterance` or a detailed message like `Unable to train XYZ application because ABC intent have zero utterances`

Comment: i am getting this error even after adding 2 utterances in the intent. What could be the issue?

Comment: check if your utterances are added on https://www.luis.ai/applications.

Comment: I hit this issue when LUIS quietly removed an utterance from my intent because a duplicate utterance was added to another intent, this lead to the intent having no utterances any more. Also worth noting the duplicate removal applies after the tokenizer has simplified the utterance.